# Retrieve data from array and display in textbox, 5 strings at a time

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files

I want to display specific arrays from a very large text file.

Below the coding is part of the file.

What I want to do is display specific strings from the text file.
For example the example shows the Footlocker page. On the Footlocker Shop page I want to retrieve the last 5 updates in the text file beginning with "footlocker" posting only Footlocker's most recent posts. I have tried many ways including `array.sort` I am not sure how you would do this. Thanks for your help.

***Footlocker's page***

```
    //declaring string
    string footlockerPosts =
        sr.ReadToEnd();
    //initialising string
    string[] footlockerArray = footlockerPosts.Split('\n');

    string[] sort = footlockerArray;
    var target = "F";
    var results = Array.FindAll(sort, f => f.Equals(target));

    for (int i = footlockerArray.Length - 1; i > footlockerArray.Length - 7; i--)
    {
        footlockerArray.Reverse();
        footlockerExistingBlogTextBox.Text += footlockerArray[i];
    }

    sr.Close();

    return;
}
```

***This is a small snippet of my file.***

***File***

> Footlocker,Rick,What a fabulous shop.
>   Footlocker,Ioela,Fantastic and incredible service.
>   Footlocker,Fisi,Can't wait to go back to shop!
>   Footlocker,Allui,Lovin' the new design and layout!
>   Footlocker,Rich,Can't wait for next season clothing range.
>   Hypebeast,Johnny,I didn’t get proper service from the shop assistant.
>   Hypebeast,Dalas,Awesome range of goods, great service.
>   Hypebeast,King,Cool music great staff.
>   Hypebeast,Nelson,Overated shop.
>   Hypebeast,Rick,Lovely place lovely people.
>   Hypebeast,Rick,What a fabulous shop.
>   Hypebeast,Ioela,Fantastic and incredible service.
>   Hypebeast,Fisi,Can't wait to go back to shop!
>   Hypebeast,Allui,Lovin' the new design and layout!
>   Hypebeast,Rich,Can't wait for next season clothing range.
>   Lonestar,Johnny,I didn’t get proper service from the waiter.
>   Lonestar,Dalas,Awesome range of food, great service.
>   Lonestar,King,Cool music great staff.
>   Lonestar,Nelson,Overated restaurant.
>   Lonestar,Rick,Lovely place lovely people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following and let me know if it gets you the results you want

```
var results = sort.Where(r => r.StartsWith(target)).Reverse();

foreach (string result in results)
        {
             footlockerExistingBlogTextBox.Text += result;
        }
```

Hope that helps!

Also just a note: There is not reason to assign another variable equal to the original array. You can remove this line `string[] sort = footlockerArray;` and point to the original footlockerArray.

Comment: it works! do you know how do I do this for 5 strings that begins with the "F" without repeating the line?

Comment: Hi there, glad I could help! I'm a bit unsure what you mean. Your original array will contain 20 items. The new results array should contain the five items that begin with F, in the reverse order in which they appear in the text file. What do you mean by "without repeating the line"?

Comment: How do I combine these two statements? var target = "F";
          var results = footlockerArray.Where(r => r.StartsWith(target)).Reverse();

        foreach (string result in results)
        {
             footlockerExistingBlogTextBox.Text += result;
        }

        for (int i = footlockerArray.Length - 1; i > footlockerArray.Length - 2; i--)
            {
                footlockerArray.Reverse();
                footlockerExistingBlogTextBox.Text += footlockerArray;
        }